# Unable to determine why I'm receiving the warning "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r

The equation which returns it is this:

```
Total_Eff[PatientDI] = (Total_Eff[PatientDI] + (QALY_PopNorm - QALY_Infert_Decr)*0.5*(0.95^CLOCK[PatientDI]))
```

where in the workspace, the objects in question have values such as:

```
> Total_Eff
[1] 12.03512  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
> QALY_PopNorm
[1] 0.9363524
> QALY_Infert_Decr
[1] 0.05609429
> CLOCK
[1] 20.716  0.000  0.000  0.000
> PatientDI
[1] 1
```

and when I input the equation manually (i.e. in the workspace after my code has finished running), I get:

```
> (Total_Eff[PatientDI] + (QALY_PopNorm - QALY_Infert_Decr)*0.5*(0.95^CLOCK[PatientDI]))
[1] 12.18721
```

with no warnings.

The issue is that I get so many warnings of this nature they drown out every other warning that might be important, and when I use "warnings()" all I see is the error message for this equation repeated over and over.

Can anyone see where the problem lies? I realize that without the entire code (some 2000 lines long) it's impossible to know exactly what's going on at all times, but I'm certain that QALY_PopNorm and QALY_Infert_Decr are ALWAYS vectors with length of 1, so I'm at a loss with regards to where the warning is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see exactly where the problem lies by converting warnings into errors and entering the debugger:

```
options(warn=2, error=recover)
```

You'll be able to examine the values of the relevant variables at the time of the warning.